# Function stops working as soon as I add 1 more variable? Adding boundaries to image based off pixel color

Tags: javascript, css, html

I've been stuck on the issue of finding a way to add boundaries to my maze game.

After posting here some time ago, It was brought to my attention that you can grab pixel/image data from the cursor, then tell the draw function not to run if this pixel was a certain color.

With this in mind, I altered my initial code from this

```
<script>
 var el = document.getElementById('can1');
 var ctx = el.getContext('2d');
 var isDrawing;
 var can = document.getElementById('can1');

 el.onmousedown = function(e) {
    isDrawing = true;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "green";
    ctx.lineWidth = 4;
    ctx.lineJoin = ctx.lineCap = 'round';
    ctx.moveTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
}

el.onmousemove = function(e) {
  if (isDrawing) {
    ctx.lineTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
};

el.onmouseup = function() {
  isDrawing = false;
};
</script>
```

to this (note this is a snippet)

```
<script>
 var el = document.getElementById('can1');
 var ctx = el.getContext('2d');
 var isDrawing;
 var can = document.getElementById('can1');
 var rgbColorData = ctx.getImageData(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, 1, 1).data; 

 el.onmousedown = function(e) {
  if (rgbColorData[0] == 255) {
  isDrawing = true;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "green";
  ctx.lineWidth = 4;
  ctx.lineJoin = ctx.lineCap = 'round';
  ctx.moveTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
}}
```

It seems as soon as I add any variable to the initial code, the whole drawing function stops working. I tested this by adding 'var random = holo;' and the whole thing stopped working for some reason.

For anyone wondering images are done with the following code

```
<script>
    var img2 = new Image();
    function test2() {
    can.width = img2.width;
    can.height = img2.height;
    ctx.drawImage(img2, 0, 0);
}
img2.src = 'http://www.hereandabove.com/cgi-bin/maze?30+30+20+5+5+0+0+0+255+255+255.jpg';
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`var rgbColorData = ctx.getImageData(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, 1, 1).data;`

There just no `e` variable at that point.

```
 el.onmousedown = function(e) {
```

... here it is.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried moving it down earlier, but no dice. Drawing no longer seems to work.

     el.onmousedown = function(e) {
        var rgbColorData = ctx.getImageData(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, 1, 1).data; 
       if (rgbColorData[0] == 255) {

Comment: 1) that not changes the fact, that `e` variable is defined only in event handler. 2) you can open error console in your browser and look at errors your code throws 3) you sholud create minimal reproducible example on something like jsFiddle, but I wonder if that will be needed after you look into console ;)